# SVG animation translate

Tags: html, svg

I try to make a next and previous button with SVG

There are square and triangle. When you see square, If you click next, It should change to triangle. And when you see triangle, If you click previous, It should change back to square.

If I click next then previous, It works perfectly. But when I try to click next again. It not works.

Here is my SVG code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
     width="300" height="300">
  <text id="previous" x="50" y="250" font-family="Verdana" font-size="30" fill="blue" >
    Prev
  </text>
  <text id="next" x="200" y="250" font-family="Verdana" font-size="30" fill="blue" >
    Next
  </text>
  <g>
  <path id="triangle" d="M450 0 L375 200 L525 200 Z" 
        stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" 
        fill="white">
        <animateColor attributeName="fill" 
                    to="rgb(0,255,0)" begin="mouseover" dur="1s" 
                    additive="sum" fill="freeze"/>
        <animateColor attributeName="fill" 
                    to="rgb(255,255,255)" begin="mouseout" dur="1s" 
                    additive="sum" fill="freeze"/>  

  </path>
  <path id="square" d="M75 0 L225 0 L225 200 L75 200 Z" 
        stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" 
        fill="white">
        <animateColor attributeName="fill" 
                    to="rgb(255,0,0)" begin="mouseover" dur="1s" 
                    additive="sum" fill="freeze"/>
        <animateColor attributeName="fill" 
                    to="rgb(255,255,255)" begin="mouseout" dur="1s" 
                    additive="sum" fill="freeze"/>

  </path>
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML"
                    type="translate" by="-300,0" begin="next.click" dur="1s"
                    keyTimes="0; 1" calcMode="spline" keySplines=".5 0 .5 1"
                    additive="sum" accumulate="sum" fill="freeze"/>
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML"
                    type="translate" by="300,0" begin="previous.click" dur="1s"
                    keyTimes="0; 1" calcMode="spline" keySplines=".5 0 .5 1"
                    additive="sum" accumulate="sum" fill="freeze"/>
</g>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This fixes it for me. Note that you should avoid animateColor and use animate instead as animateColor is deprecated in the SVG specification.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
     width="300" height="300">
  <text id="previous" x="50" y="250" font-family="Verdana" font-size="30" fill="blue" >
    Prev
  </text>
  <text id="next" x="200" y="250" font-family="Verdana" font-size="30" fill="blue" >
    Next
  </text>
  <g>
  <path id="triangle" d="M450 0 L375 200 L525 200 Z" 
        stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" 
        fill="white">
        <animate attributeName="fill" 
                    to="rgb(0,255,0)" begin="mouseover" dur="1s" 
                    additive="sum" fill="freeze"/>
        <animate attributeName="fill" 
                    to="rgb(255,255,255)" begin="mouseout" dur="1s" 
                    additive="sum" fill="freeze"/>  

  </path>
  <path id="square" d="M75 0 L225 0 L225 200 L75 200 Z" 
        stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" 
        fill="white">
        <animate attributeName="fill" 
                    to="rgb(255,0,0)" begin="mouseover" dur="1s" 
                    additive="sum" fill="freeze"/>
        <animate attributeName="fill" 
                    to="rgb(255,255,255)" begin="mouseout" dur="1s" 
                    additive="sum" fill="freeze"/>

  </path>

  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML"
                    type="translate" from="0,0" by="-300,0" begin="next.click" dur="1s"
                    keyTimes="0; 1" calcMode="spline" keySplines=".5 0 .5 1"
                    fill="freeze"/>
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML"
                    type="translate" from="-300,0" by="300,0" begin="previous.click" dur="1s"
                    keyTimes="0; 1" calcMode="spline" keySplines=".5 0 .5 1"
                    fill="freeze"/>
</g>

</body>
</html>
```